# How to get the angle between the imaginary inner common tangents when two ellipse intersect with each other

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, conic-sections, projective-geometry

This question is a follow-up on the previous question asked [in this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4025052/how-to-get-the-angle-between-the-inner-common-tangents-to-two-general-ellipse) where we discussed a strategy to find the angle between inner common tangents to two ellipse whose equations are given by:

$ AX^{2}+BXY+CY^{2}+DX+EY+F=0 $

In that approach, we **did not use any equation solver** and was able to get the angle between inner common tangents by just using the linear algebra and the concepts of projective geometry which made the solutions very computationally efficient. I am looking for a solution along those lines for a slightly different problem.

In the last thread we did not realize that the two ellipse can intersect with each other and the imaginary tangents would still exist. I am using the word **imaginary** because if the two ellipse intersect then there is no physical meaning of inner common tangents.

Usually, there will be three cases:

1. In the first case, the two ellipse do not intersect and the approach discussed in the earlier thread would work to find the inner common tangent angle. This angle will be 0 degrees when the two ellipse are infinitely apart and keeps on increasing as the two ellipse comes closer and closer. It can be noted that this angle will always be less than 180 degrees because the two ellipse never intersect.

[image]

2. In the second case, the two ellipse will intersect each other at only one point with no overlap and as a result the two inner common tangents will coincide with each other and angle between them would be exactly 180 degrees.
   [image]
3. In the third case, the two ellipse will overlap and intersect at two, three or four points. In this case, the angle between the inner common tangents should be 180 degrees + some complex number. The magnitude of this complex number would represent the degree of penetration. Greater magnitude represents greater penetration.
   [image]

To illustrate this **imaginary** tangent concept for a circle, let us consider that the angle between inner common tangents is given by the following equation:
\begin{equation}
\theta = 2\ sin^{-1}(\frac{R_1 + R_2}{r}) \end{equation}

where $R_1$ and $R_2$ are the radii of two circles, $r$ is the distance between the centre of the two circles. These quantities can be referred from the following figure:
[image]

Now, it can be seen that this angle $\theta$ is always defined even when the two circles intersect with each other. If they are non-intersecting $(R_1+R_2<r)$ then the angle would be purely real, if they are intersecting $(R_1+R_2>r)$ then the angle is 180 degrees + some complex number and finally if they touch each other at only one point $(R_1+R_2=r)$ then this angle would be 180 degrees. Usually, the more the magnitude of complex number, the deeper the overlap of two entities.

This concept is well defined for the case of circle. However, there is an equivalent concept of imaginary tangents in case of ellipse and I am not aware of how to compute this imaginary angle. I only know non-deterministic method of doing that. I hope my question is clear. Please help me out with the deterministic solution for the ellipse case. Thanks!

Comment: This will be a bit different, but if you know the slopes of the lines,  then one can find the angle between them [like this](https://www.basic-mathematics.com/angle-between-two-lines.html). I suppose you could take the derivative of the ellipse and equate them to find the common tangent.

Comment: *"I am not aware of how to compute this imaginary angle. I only know an iterative way of doing that."* Please describe your iterative way, providing a few specific examples. This will help people confirm that their calculations of the target angle match your interpretation. Plus, your algorithm may provide someone with a jumping-off point for a deterministic solution, saving them from wasting time duplicating your effort.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52809/circle-bitangent-angles) for how to find one of the other angles, in the real case. They seem to be $2\sin^{-1}(\frac{R_1 + R_2}{r}), \sin^{-1}(\frac{R_1 + R_2}{r})+\sin^{-1}(\frac{R_1 - R_2}{r}), 2\sin^{-1}(\frac{R_1 - R_2}{r})$ and the like.

Comment: @Blue the iterative way is for arbitrary shapes and that can take this discussion into a different direction. That method tries to convert the arbitrary shape into an equivalent circle for computation of that angle because for two circles we have a formula. 

However, if one is interested in checking if their solution is correct then they can take the major and minor axes length of ellipse equal so that the ellipse decomposes into a circle. And we have a formula for the determination of that angle for a circle.


Iterative method (Section C): https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/pdf/10.2514/1.G002932

Comment: @KashishDhal I think that the previous algorithm for finding the four tangents works in all cases that you have listed. You just have to allow it to work with complex numbers (before, I wrote a python version using only real numbers because I am not familiar with the complex number packages for python, like numpy with complex numbers). You would be able to find the tangents exactly the same way. What is a bit problematic however is deciding what you would call inner and outer tangents.

Comment: @KashishDhal for example, the forth example, where you have two ellipses intersecting in four points, you can see that there are four tangents but technically they are all external, there are no internal ones and definitely there are no complex tangents either. The complex (inner?) tangents appear only in the case of two ellipses intersecting at two real points. And these two tangents are complex conjugates of each other.

Comment: @Futurologist we can deal with the complex numbers in MATLAB, that should not be a problem. However, let's say we have only 2 intersection for now, how would one find that complex number? For example, in the case of two circles of radii 5 each, if r=1, then complex number = - 5.9864, if r = 0.001, then it is -19.8070. How would one find this number? This is definitely not a angle?  Can you please shed some light on the mathematics behind that computation, I will probably write code in MATLAB and share a code here where we can discuss?

Comment: @Futurologist I tried to solve the case of two circles (R1 = 5, R2 = 5, r = 1) with your code and I am only getting two solutions. Other two solutions are [Inf*i Inf Nan] and [-Inf*i Inf NaN] where Inf (infinity) and NaN(not a number). They don't tell much about inner common tangents.

Comment: @KashishDhal Yes, that's because everything is the same up to the point where you select the solutions in the special coordinates. In the real case they were selected as the square root of the quotient of the two last entries along the diagonal of the degenerate matrix in special coordinates. In the complex case, one needs to take the firs two elements from the diagonal, so that's where it is different. You get these results because of division by zero. If it is not super urgent, please give me a bit of time to think of a patch. Work's a a bit crazy these few days...

Comment: @Futurologist sure, thanks, I will wait, when you find a solution, please post in the answer. Also, please verify for two circles (major axis = minor axis) if the complex number matches what we get from the formula for the circle.

Comment: @Futurologist would you be able to share a sudo code (for only complex case) while you are thinking about a patch? In any case, I will have to convert your Python code into MATLAB so a sudo code will also do the work for me. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New updated code.**

This seems to work better:

```
'''
angle between inner tangents between two intersecting ellipses, newer version
'''

import numpy as np
import math
import cmath

'''
####### FUNCTIONS IMPORTANT FOR THE CALCULATION #######
'''
    
def homogenize(x):
    return np.array([x[0], x[1], 1])

# transforming the vector of six coefficients
# of a quadratic equation with two variables into a matrix of 
# the corresponding conic 
def conic_from_equation(eq):
    '''
    eq is an np.array vector of the quadratic equation's six coefficients
    eq[0]*x**2 + eq[1]*x*y + eq[2]*y**2 + eq[3]*x + eq[4]*y + eq[5] = 0
    conc is a symmetric matrix of the bilinier form of the quadratic equation
    '''
    return np.array([[2*eq[0],   eq[1],   eq[3]],
                     [  eq[1], 2*eq[2],   eq[4]],
                     [  eq[3],   eq[4], 2*eq[5]]]) / 2

# transformaing the matrix of a conic into a vector of six coefficients
# of a quadratic equation with two variables
def equation_from_conic(C):
    '''
    c[0]*x**2 + c[1]*x*y + c[2]*y**2 + c[3]*x + c[4]*y + c[5] = 0
    '''
    return np.array([C[0,0], 2*C[0,1], C[1,1], 2*C[0,2], 2*C[1,2], C[2,2]]) 

# obtaining the conic dual to a given conic, 
# both represented as symmetric 3x3 matrices
def dual_conic(conic):
    return np.linalg.inv(conic)

# given a pair of conics, as a pair of symmetric 3x3 matrices, 
# calculate the vector k = (k[0], k[1], k[2]) of values for each of which 
# the conic c1 - k[i]*c2 from the pencil of conics c1 - t*c2 
# is a degenerate conic (the anti-symmetric product of a pair of linear forms) 
# and also find the matrix U 
# of the projective transformation that simplifies the geometry of 
# the pair of conics, the geometry of the pencil c1 - t*c2 in general, 
# as well as the geometry of the three degenerate conics in particular  
def trivialization_of(conic1, conic2):
    '''
    c1 and c2 are 3 by 3 symmetric matrices of two conics (possibly dual)
    '''
    c21 = np.linalg.inv(conic2).dot(conic1)
    k, U = np.linalg.eig(c21)
    return k, U     

# find the common points, i.e. points of intersection of a pair of conics
# represented by a pair of symmetric matrices
def find_intersection_points(c1, c2):
    k, U = trivialization_of(c1, c2)
    L1 = (U.T).dot((c1 - k[0]*c2).dot(U))
    L2 = (U.T).dot((c1 - k[1]*c2).dot(U))
    x_0 = cmath.sqrt(-(L2[2,2] / L2[0,0]))
    y_0 = cmath.sqrt(-(L1[2,2] / L1[1,1]))
    sol = np.array([[ x_0,  y_0, 1], 
                    [-x_0, -y_0, 1],
                    [-x_0,  y_0, 1],
                    [ x_0, -y_0, 1]])
    sol = sol.dot(U.T)
    return sol

# find the three coefficients of all four common tangents to a pair of conics
# make sure that the conics do have four common tangents, 
# which is the generic situation
def find_common_tangents(c1, c2):
    dc1 = dual_conic(c1)
    dc2 = dual_conic(c2)
    return find_intersection_points(dc1, dc2)

# if the two conics are ellipses, they do not intersect the line at infinity.
# by polarity, the poles of the line at infinity are 
# the (affine and in fact metric) centers of the ellipses and are located
# inside the ellipses each. We use them to detect the inner tangents and 
# to orient the vectors normal to these tangents in a way 
# so that the angle between these two normal vectors is the vector on the picture    
def dual_to_infinity_line(conic):
    p = dual_conic(conic).dot(np.array([0,0,1]))
    return homogenize( p[0:2] / p[2] )

# find the common inner tangents between a pair of conics, 
# represented as 3x3 symmetric matrices, with properly oriented normal vectors
def find_common_inner_tangents(c1, c2):
    tn = find_common_tangents(c1, c2)
    p1 = dual_to_infinity_line(c1)
    p2 = dual_to_infinity_line(c2)
    # boolean vector, true if inner tangent false if not
    is_inner_tangent = np.logical_or(tn.real.dot(p1)*tn.real.dot(p2) < 0, tn.imag.dot(p1)*tn.imag.dot(p2) < 0)
    tn = tn[ is_inner_tangent, : ]
    # reorient one of the normal vectors so that they give us the proper angle
    if tn.real[0,:].dot(p1)*tn.real[1,:].dot(p1) > 0 or tn.imag[0,:].dot(p1)*tn.imag[1,:].dot(p1) > 0:
        tn[1,:] = - tn[1,:]
    return tn

# calculate the angle between a pair of line, given by their three coefficients
def angle_bn_C_lines(line1, line2):
    theta = line1[0:2].dot(line2[0:2]) / ( cmath.sqrt( line1[0:2].dot(line1[0:2])*line2[0:2].dot(line2[0:2])) ) 
    return cmath.acos(theta).conjugate()

# calculate the proper angle between the inner or complex tangents of two quadratic equations
# that represent a pair of conics, hopefully non-intersecting
def angle_bn_inner_tangents_of(eq_of_conic1, eq_of_conic2):
    c1 = conic_from_equation(eq_of_conic1)
    c2 = conic_from_equation(eq_of_conic2)
    tn = find_common_inner_tangents(c1, c2)
    return angle_bn_C_lines(tn[0,:], tn[1,:])
    
'''
####### END OF FUCTIONS IMPORTANT FOR THE CALCULATION #######
'''


'''
####### auxiliary functions to handle the test scenario: 
'''

def cos_sin(angle_deg):
    return math.cos(angle_deg*math.pi/180), math.sin(angle_deg*math.pi/180)

def rotation(cs_sn):
    return np.array([[cs_sn[0], -cs_sn[1]], 
                     [cs_sn[1],  cs_sn[0]]])
    
def isom(angle, translation):
    '''
    isometry from global coordinate system (world system) 
    to conic-aligned coordinate system (conic attached) 
    '''
    cos_, sin_ = cos_sin(-angle)
    tr = - rotation((cos_, sin_)).dot(translation)
    return np.array([[ cos_, -sin_, tr[0]], 
                     [ sin_,  cos_, tr[1]], 
                     [    0,     0,    1 ]])

# calculating the conic defined by a pair of axes' lengths, 
# axes rotation angle and center of the conic  
def Conic(major, minor, angle, center):
    D = np.array([[minor**2,        0,                 0],
                  [       0, major**2,                 0], 
                  [       0,        0, -(minor*major)**2]])
    U = isom(angle, center)
    return (U.T).dot(D.dot(U))     

   
'''
####### end of auxiliary functions
'''


'''
test
'''

a1 = 5
b1 = 4.95
cntr1 = np.array([0,0])
w1 = 45

Eq1 = equation_from_conic(Conic(a1, b1, w1, cntr1))
Co1 = conic_from_equation(Eq1)

a2 = 1
b2 = .95
cntr2 = np.array([3,0])
w2 = 120

Eq2 = equation_from_conic(Conic(a2, b2, w2, cntr2))
Co2 = conic_from_equation(Eq2)

t4 = find_common_tangents(Co1, Co2)
print('all four tangents: ')
print(t4)
print('')
it = find_common_inner_tangents(Co1, Co2)
print('the inner tangents only: ')
print(it)

print('')

print('angle between inner tangents calculated by algorithm: ')
print( angle_bn_inner_tangents_of(Eq1, Eq2) )
print('')
print('angle calculation for circular approximation of the test case: ')
print('angle of internal tangents of a circle: ')
print(2*cmath.asin((a1+a2)/cntr2[0]))
print('angle of external tangents of a circle: ')
print(2*cmath.asin(abs(a1-a2)/cntr2[0]))
```

**Previous code.**

It seems like this code does what you want.
It treats the case of real inner tangents of disjoint ellipses or the case of two complex tangents of two ellipses, intersecting at two real points. For circles, the result seems to match the elementary formula.

```
'''
angle between inner tangents of two non-intersecting ellipses
or the complex angle between the two complex tangents of two
intersecting ellipses at two real points 
'''

import numpy as np
import math
import cmath

'''
####### FUNCTIONS IMPORTANT FOR THE CALCULATION #######
'''
    
def homogenize(x):
    return np.array([x[0], x[1], 1])

# transforming the vector of six coefficients
# of a quadratic equation with two variables into a matrix of 
# the corresponding conic 
def conic_from_equation(eq):
    '''
    eq is an np.array vector of the equadratic equation's six coefficients
    eq[0]*x**2 + eq[1]*x*y + eq[2]*y**2 + eq[3]*x + eq[4]*y + eq[5] = 0
    conc is a symmetric matrix of the bilinier form of the quadratic equation
    '''
    return np.array([[2*eq[0],   eq[1],   eq[3]],
                     [  eq[1], 2*eq[2],   eq[4]],
                     [  eq[3],   eq[4], 2*eq[5]]]) / 2

# transforming the matrix of a conic into a vector of six coefficients
# of a quadratic equation with two variables
def equation_from_conic(C):
    '''
    c[0]*x**2 + c[1]*x*y + c[2]*y**2 + c[3]*x + c[4]*y + c[5] = 0
    '''
    return np.array([C[0,0], 2*C[0,1], C[1,1], 2*C[0,2], 2*C[1,2], C[2,2]]) 

# obtaining the conic dual to a given conic, 
# both represented as symmetric 3x3 matrices
def dual_conic(conic):
    return np.linalg.inv(conic)

# given a pair of conics, as a pair of symmetric 3x3 matrices, 
# calculate the vector k = (k[0], k[1], k[2]) of values for each of which 
# the conic c1 - k[i]*c2 from the pencil of conics c1 - t*c2 
# is a degenerate conic (the symmetric tensor product of a pair of linear forms) 
# and also find the matrix U 
# of the projective transformation that simplifies the geometry of 
# the pair of conics, the geometry of the pencil c1 - t*c2 in general, 
# as well as the geometry of the three degenerate conics in particular  
def trivialization_of(conic1, conic2):
    '''
    c1 and c2 are 3 by 3 symmetric matrices of two conics (possibly dual)
    '''
    c21 = np.linalg.inv(conic2).dot(conic1)
    k, U = np.linalg.eig(c21)
    return k, U   

# find the common points, i.e. points of intersection of a pair of conics
# represented by a pair of symmetric matrices
def find_intersection_points(c1, c2):
    k, U = trivialization_of(c1, c2)
    L1 = (U.T).dot((c1 - k[0]*c2).dot(U))
    L2 = (U.T).dot((c1 - k[1]*c2).dot(U))
    acc = 1e-12
    are_complex = (k.imag > acc).any()
    if are_complex:
        x_0 = cmath.sqrt(-L2[2,2] / L2[0,0])
        y_0 = cmath.sqrt(-L1[2,2] / L1[1,1])        
    else:
        x_0 = math.sqrt(abs(L2[2,2] / L2[0,0]))
        y_0 = math.sqrt(abs(L1[2,2] / L1[1,1]))
    sol = np.array([[ x_0,  y_0, 1], 
                    [-x_0,  y_0, 1],
                    [-x_0, -y_0, 1],
                    [ x_0, -y_0, 1]])
    sol = sol.dot(U.T)
    return sol, are_complex

# find the three coefficients of all four common tangents to a pair of conics
# make sure that the conics do have four common tangents, 
# which is the generic situation
def find_common_tangents(c1, c2):
    dc1 = dual_conic(c1)
    dc2 = dual_conic(c2)
    return find_intersection_points(dc1, dc2)

# if the two conics are ellipses, they do not intersect the line at infinity.
# by polarity, the poles of the line at infinity are 
# the (affine and in fact metric) centers of the ellipses and are located
# inside the ellipses each. We use them to detect the inner tangents and 
# to orient the vectors normal to these tangents in a way 
# so that the angle between these two normal vectors is the vector on the picture    
def dual_to_infinity_line(conic):
    p = dual_conic(conic).dot(np.array([0,0,1]))
    return homogenize( p[0:2] / p[2] )

# find the common inner tangents between a pair of conics, 
# represented as 3x3 symmetric matrices, with properly oriented normal vectors
def find_common_inner_tangents(c1, c2):
    tn, complex_tangents = find_common_tangents(c1, c2)
    if not complex_tangents:
        p1 = dual_to_infinity_line(c1)
        p2 = dual_to_infinity_line(c2)
        # boolean vector, true if inner tangent false if not
        is_inner_tangent = ( tn.dot(p1)*tn.dot(p2) < 0 )
        tn = tn[ is_inner_tangent, : ]
        # reorient one of the normal vectors so that they give us the proper angle
        if tn[0,:].dot(p1)*tn[1,:].dot(p1) > 0:
            tn[1,:] = - tn[1,:]
    else:
        acc = 1e-12
        is_complex_line = np.logical_or(abs(tn[:,0].imag) > acc, 
                                        abs(tn[:,1].imag) > acc, 
                                        abs(tn[:,2].imag) > acc)
        tn = tn[ is_complex_line, :]
    return tn, complex_tangents

# calculate the angle between a pair of line, given by their three coefficients
def angle_bn_R_lines(line1, line2):
    theta = line1[0:2].dot(line2[0:2]) / math.sqrt( line1[0:2].dot(line1[0:2])*line2[0:2].dot(line2[0:2]))
    return math.acos(theta) #*180/np.pi

def angle_bn_C_lines(line1, line2):
    theta = line1[0:2].dot(line2[0:2]) / ( cmath.sqrt( line1[0:2].dot(line1[0:2]))*cmath.sqrt(line2[0:2].dot(line2[0:2])) ) 
    return cmath.acos(theta)

# calculate the proper angle between the inner or complex tangents of two quadratic equations
# that represent a pair of conics, hopefully non-intersecting
def angle_bn_inner_tangents_of(eq_of_conic1, eq_of_conic2):
    c1 = conic_from_equation(eq_of_conic1)
    c2 = conic_from_equation(eq_of_conic2)
    tn, complex_tangents = find_common_inner_tangents(c1, c2)
    if complex_tangents: 
        return angle_bn_C_lines(tn[0,:], tn[1,:])
    else:
        return angle_bn_R_lines(tn[0,:], tn[1,:])
    
'''
####### END OF FUCTIONS IMPORTANT FOR THE CALCULATION #######
'''


'''
####### auxiliary functions to handle the test scenario: 
'''

def cos_sin(angle_deg):
    return math.cos(angle_deg*math.pi/180), math.sin(angle_deg*math.pi/180)

def rotation(cs_sn):
    return np.array([[cs_sn[0], -cs_sn[1]], 
                     [cs_sn[1],  cs_sn[0]]])
    
def isom(angle, translation):
    '''
    isometry from global coordinate system (world system) 
    to conic-aligned coordinate system (conic attached) 
    '''
    cos_, sin_ = cos_sin(-angle)
    tr = - rotation((cos_, sin_)).dot(translation)
    return np.array([[ cos_, -sin_, tr[0]], 
                     [ sin_,  cos_, tr[1]], 
                     [    0,     0,    1 ]])

# calculating the conic defined by a pair of axes' lengths, 
# axes rotation angle and center of the conic  
def Conic(major, minor, angle, center):
    D = np.array([[minor**2,        0,                 0],
                  [       0, major**2,                 0], 
                  [       0,        0, -(minor*major)**2]])
    U = isom(angle, center)
    return (U.T).dot(D.dot(U))     

   
'''
####### end of auxiliary functions
'''
#%%
'''
Example of finding the angle between the common tangents of a pair of conics:
conic 1 (circle): major axis = 2, minor axis = 2, angle = 0, center = (0,0)
conic 2 (circle): major axis = 3, minor axis = 3, angle = 0, center = (4,0)
'''

a = 2
b = 2
cntr = np.array([0,0])
w = 0

Eq1 = equation_from_conic(Conic(a, b, w, cntr))
Co1 = conic_from_equation(Eq1)

a = 3
b = 3
cntr = np.array([4,0])
w = 0

Eq2 = equation_from_conic(Conic(a, b, w, cntr))
Co2 = conic_from_equation(Eq2)

four_tngs = find_common_tangents(Co1, Co2)

#inner_tngs = find_common_inner_tangents(Co1, Co2) 

print( angle_bn_inner_tangents_of(Eq1, Eq2) )
print(2*cmath.asin((2+3)/4))
```

$$$$

**Older Post.**

Today I had some time to experiment with the code I wrote in the previous post. Theoretically, the approach should be exactly the same as the case of four real tangents. However, the only major hassle I am seeing for now is the complex arithmetic. In the function `find_common_points()` some square roots are calculated, which works fine for real numbers, but when the entries of the trivialized degenerate conics `L1` and `L2` become complex (and they do in the case of two ellipses intersecting at exactly two points), then one needs to carefully calculate the appropriate complex square root. The rest is the same. With two complex tangents and two real ones, you choose the complex to be "inner" and calculate a complex dot product divided by complex norms, which will give you a complex number. After that you can take complex `arccos()` of that. Whether this scheme leads to the same  elementary circle calculation you show in your post, is unclear for now, although the fact that all of these are complex holomorphic functions of several variables that overlap in the real case suggest that it is possible these constructions match due to the rigidity of holomorphic prolongations.

Comment: In a comment earlier, you mentioned that "In the real case they were selected as the square root of the quotient of the two last entries along the diagonal of the degenerate matrix in special coordinates. In the complex case, one needs to take the first two elements from the diagonal, so that's where it is different."

Do we need to make any changes regarding this?

Comment: @KashishDhal Forget about that, there is no such difference with the real case. Everything is the same. The only difference is the complex arithmetic. See the update of my post.

Comment: Thanks, I checked that it gives correct results for the case of circle. I will check this for ellipse and update you about that!

Comment: this code doesn't give correct answer when one circle is completely inside the other circle. In that case, all the tangents are complex and your code picks first two from ```tn```  Is there any way, we can pick the correct complex tangents which matches the elementary formula. If you want to check the case I am running, it is the following: ```x1 = 0; y1 = 0; x2 = 3; y2 = 0; a1 = 5; b1 = 5; a2 = 1; b2 = 1;```

Comment: @KashishDhal of course not, it is for the case of externally non-intersecting ellipses or ellipses with two common real points. I did not designed the case of four complex tangents. One reason is I do not know in that case what is inner and outer tangent. This concept disappears in the complex plane. You have to specify exactly how you wanted defined, otherwise I wouldn't know.

Comment: Well if I manually pick two out of four complex tangents, then it gives the correct result as per the elementary formula. I do not know which two of them to pick but I know that two of them gives correct result. The complex part of inner common tangent angle represents the degree of penetration. The more the penetration, the more the value. I do not know more than this. The only other thing, I know, is to check from elementary formula, if that rings some bell.

Comment: @KashishDhal I suspect one needs to pick a pair of complex conjugate tangents. both such pairs may give the same result. I will have to check that.

Comment: I just re-verified for the above case I mentioned in the comment, I get two different answers of inner common tangent angle for two different complex pairs, those are:
```3.1416 - 2.6339i``` and ```3.1416 - 1.5907i```.
Of the two, first one is correct.

Comment: This code also starts giving trouble with only 2 intersection points for the case of ellipse when the degree overlap exceeds a certain value. I looked into your code and realized that after a certain degree of overlap, all the tangents become complex so choosing the correct tangents is even necessary for only 2 intersecting points. For example, take the case, ```x1 = 0; y1 = 0; x2 = 1.5; y2 = 0; a1 = 5; b1 = 3; a2 = 5; b2 = 3; alpha1 = pi/2; alpha2 = pi/2;``` Also another thing I noticed is that when the center of one ellipse lie on the boundary of another then I don't get correct result.

Comment: Sorry, I should not have said "when the degree overlap exceeds a certain value". Upon re-verifying, it looks like the code only fails at a few configurations for the case of intersecting ellipse at 2 points. For example, the case I mentioned in previous comment fails but the cases which are neighborhood of this case (more or less overlap) still works. Another case that fails is ```x1 = 0; y1 = 0; x2 = 1.0; y2 = 0; a1 = 5; b1 = 3; a2 = 5; b2 = 3; alpha1 = pi/2; alpha2 = pi/2;```

Comment: @KashishDhal I updated the code and made it a bit more consolidated.

Comment: Thanks, let me test it for a few configurations. I will update you about the results! Meanwhile, may you please explain the logic you used to detect inner tangents when all are complex?

Comment: Hello @Futurologist, I found one small problem while executing your code only for a few cases. For example, ```x1 = 0; y1 = 0; x2 = 2.5; y2 = 2.5; a1 = 5; b1 = 3; a2 = 5; b2 = 3; alpha1 = pi/2; alpha2 = pi/2;```  The re-orientation part of code (Line 101) does not behave properly, because the value of ```tn.real[0,:].dot(p1)*tn.real[1,:].dot(p1)``` in your case (Python) and my case (MATLAB) are ```1.92e-33 and -9.1e-33``` respectively. Although, they both are close to ```0```, your code seems to works but mine doesn't.  I am not able to resolve this because of precision error. Any clue?

Comment: Looks like these lines works as better replacement for Line 98: ```is_inner_tangent = np.logical_or(tn.real.dot(p1)*tn.real.dot(p2) < -1e-12, tn.imag.dot(p1)*tn.imag.dot(p2) < -1e-12)``` 
Ans this for Line 101:
```if tn.real[0,:].dot(p1)*tn.real[1,:].dot(p1) > -1e-12 or tn.imag[0,:].dot(p1)*tn.imag[1,:].dot(p1) > -1e-12:``` 

Your thoughts? Your Python code also fails for this case: ```a1 = 5,  b1 = 3 cntr1 = np.array([0,0]) w1 = 90  a2 = 5 b2 = 3 cntr2 = np.array([1.5,2]) w2 = 90```

Answer (score 1):

This will be a bit different, but if you know the slopes of the lines, then one can find the angle between them [like this](https://www.basic-mathematics.com/angle-between-two-lines.html). I suppose you could take the derivative of the ellipse and equate them to find the common tangent.

There is a great short video by “Senzen” and at the end of the video, a formula for your problem is shown. [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BPgq2AudoEo). The derivative will give the tangent line slopes and will turn the constant into 0.

$$\mathrm{C=\frac{d}{dx}\left(A((y-b)sinθ+(x-a)cosθ)^2+B((y-b) cosθ-(x-a) sinθ)^2=1\right),D= \frac{d}{dx}\left(A_2((y-b_2)sinθ+(x-a_2)cosθ)^2+B_2((y-b_2) cosθ-(x-a_2) sinθ)^2=1\right)=0}$$

To find the slope of the lines, simply solve for x in:

$$\mathrm{C=D\implies 2 A (cos(θ) + sin(θ) y'(x)) ((x - a) cos(θ) + sin(θ) (y(x) - b)) + 2 B (cos(θ) y'(x) - sin(θ)) (cos(θ) (y(x) - b) - (x - a) sin(θ)) = 2 A_2(cos(θ) + sin(θ) y'(x)) ((x - a_2) cos(θ) + sin(θ) (y(x) - b_2)) + 2 B_2 (cos(θ) y'(x) - sin(θ)) (cos(θ) (y(x) - b_2) - (x - a_2) sin(θ))=0}$$

Once the values for x are found which solve the equation, plug these into either C(x) or D(x) as each solved value will give the same slope. When you found 2 lines of slope $m_{1,2}$, the angle will be given in closed form as:$$\mathrm{\theta=tan^{-1}\left(\frac{m_2-m_1}{1+m_1m_2}\right)}$$

Here is a [demo](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bq2chd9moa). Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: If you look at the earlier thread that I linked in the question, we have already found the tangents and also the angle between them. And we did not have to solve any equations for that, it was all done by linear algebra (using the concepts of projective geometry) which makes it computationally efficient. 

I am looking for the solution in the case the two ellipse intersect with each other. Your solution is more computationally intensive and gives the tangents which physically exist, however, I am looking for tangents which are imaginary and the angle between them.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at imaginary tangents:

Angle between real tangents and imaginary roots of non-intersecting ellipses  can be found just as between imaginary tangents and real roots of intersecting ellipses. There is a one to one correspondence. The following is given even if it may appear vague at the outset.

Consider an analogous situation with respect to tangent points of a simpler conic, the parabola instead of an ellipse.

$$ y = ax^2+bx+c=0  ,\; \Delta= b^2-4 ac \;\tag1$$

When parabola does not intersect x-axis, the complex roots are given by

$$(x_1,y_1)= \dfrac{ -b\pm \sqrt{-\Delta}}{2a}\tag2$$

and tangent points from the closest point on x-axis are given by

$$(x_1,y_1)= \left( \dfrac{ -b\pm \sqrt{-\Delta}}{2a}, \dfrac{-\Delta}{2a}\right)\tag3 $$

Angle between imaginary tangents
$$ \gamma= 2 \tan^{-1}\dfrac{\dfrac{\sqrt{-\Delta}}{2a}}{\dfrac{-\Delta}{2a}} = 2 \cot^{-1}{\sqrt{-\Delta}} \tag4$$

An example is the disposition of tangents and depiction of complex roots in the complex plane :

$$ x^2-3x+4=0, \text{Roots}: ((3\pm i \sqrt{7})/2,7/2)$$

Real roots and imaginary tangents occur when the parabola is brought down to intersect x-axis

$$  y= ax^2+bx +c- \frac{ 4ac-b^2}{2a} \tag 5 $$

with real roots of parabola

$$(x_0,y_0)= \dfrac{ -b\pm \sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}\tag6$$

in the example

$$ x^2-3x +\frac12=0 \tag 7 $$

[image]